# Как правильно вычислить ширину картинок в JS?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, изображения

Пробую делать слайдер на JS по [данному](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM7zWNn4IPE) гайду.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let line = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0];
  let imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('line-item');
  let sliderWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0].offsetWidth;
  let widthArr = [];
  let lineWidth = 0;

  let step = 0,
    offset = 0;
  // console.log(sliderWidth);

  for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    widthArr.push(imgs[i].offsetWidth);
    // lineWidth += Math.ceil(imgs[i].offsetWidth);
    lineWidth += imgs[i].offsetWidth;
  }

  line.style.width = lineWidth + 'px';

  console.log(widthArr);

  function doSlide() {
    if (step === -1) {
      step = 0;
      line.style.left = '0px';
    } else {
      let diff = lineWidth - (offset + imgs[step].offsetWidth);
      if (diff > sliderWidth) {
        offset += imgs[step].offsetWidth;
        line.style.left = -offset + 'px';
        step++;
      } else {
        offset = lineWidth - sliderWidth;
        line.style.left = -offset + 'px';
        step = -1;
        offset = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  document.onclick = doSlide;
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 400px;
  /* height: 600px; */
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
}

.line-item {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.blok {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.blok-1 {
  width: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="line">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559132837-f5007d4fb2fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559149740-88c6a43a4d09?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559163499-413811fb2344?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559200856-016e4562742d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559295628-07113de3334f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559234597-acca201b4a01?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <div class="line-item blok"></div>
      <div class="line-item blok-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

При загрузке документа я с помощью `offsetWidth` рассчитываю ширину каждого элемента в блоке `line`, а потом задаю ширину для `line` как сумму всех `offsetWidth`. Все элементы внутри этого блока выравнены с помощью `float:left;` и они встают в линию друг за другом только тогда, когда ширина позволяет им это сделать.

Проблема в том, что, почему-то, ширина получается на 1 пиксель меньше нужной и последний элемент внутри `line` не помещается в линию и встает снизу. Это можно исправить, задав вручную ширину для `line`, равную очень много пикселей, например `width: 9999999px` или что-то в этом духе

**Но вопрос в другом:**

1. Почему js подсчитывает ширину элементов так, что она получается чуток меньше, чем нужно?
2. Почему у некоторых картинок  Chrome отображает ширину как дробную, хотя она целая и как узнать значение ширины с дробной частью?
   [image]

Comment: Здесь можно записать `lineWidth += (imgs[i].offsetWidth + 1);` чтобы наверняка)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, это да. Можно даже просто изначально блоку `line` в стилях задать очень большое значение `width` и не парится с этим в js, но вопрос в том, почему js неправильно посчитал ширину и откуда у картинок взялось дробное значение в ширине?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что ширина изображений, возвращаемая свойством `offsetWidth` действительно недостаточно точная. Для точных вычислений можно воспользоваться `getBoundingClientRect()`.

> откуда у картинок взялось дробное значение в ширине

Возьмем для примера первую картинку https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559132837-f5007d4fb2fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60.

У нее оригинальные размеры **700х467**. Вы задаете высоту всем картинкам **600** пикселей, следовательно ширина картинки станет `700*(600/467) = 899.3576017130621`

Пример:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let line = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0];
  let imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('line-item');
  let sliderWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0].offsetWidth;
  let widthArr = [];
  let lineWidth = 0;

  let step = 0,
    offset = 0;
  // console.log(sliderWidth);

  for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    widthArr.push(imgs[i].offsetWidth);
    console.log(imgs[i].offsetWidth, imgs[i].getBoundingClientRect().width);
    lineWidth += imgs[i].getBoundingClientRect().width;
  }
  console.log(lineWidth);
  line.style.width = lineWidth + 'px';



  function doSlide() {
    if (step === -1) {
      step = 0;
      line.style.left = '0px';
    } else {
      let diff = lineWidth - (offset + imgs[step].offsetWidth);
      if (diff > sliderWidth) {
        offset += imgs[step].offsetWidth;
        line.style.left = -offset + 'px';
        step++;
      } else {
        offset = lineWidth - sliderWidth;
        line.style.left = -offset + 'px';
        step = -1;
        offset = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  document.onclick = doSlide;
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 400px;
  /* height: 600px; */
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
}

.line-item {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.blok {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.blok-1 {
  width: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="line">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559132837-f5007d4fb2fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559149740-88c6a43a4d09?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559163499-413811fb2344?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559200856-016e4562742d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559295628-07113de3334f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559234597-acca201b4a01?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60" alt="" class="line-item">
      <div class="line-item blok"></div>
      <div class="line-item blok-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```